# Is is possible to directly set a string value for NSMutableString?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsmutablestring

I can create a regular `NSString` easily:

```
NSString *string = @"string value";    // Case 1
```

Is it possible to do something like this?

```
NSMutableString *mutableString = @"mutableString value";    // Case 2
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can initialize the string as mentioned in some of the other answers, but for constant strings like that, I prefer to send the `-mutableCopy` message:

```
NSString* string = @"string value";
NSMutableString* mutableString = [@"mutableString value" mutableCopy];
```

It just feels easy to read to me, but it's a matter of style preference.

Comment: Jason, mutableString is autorelease obj?

Comment: @user1182731 You can't send the message `mutableString`, it's not defined for `NSString`. You can send `mutableCopy`, which is an ownership method since it has `copy` in the message name. If you're not using ARC, you will be responsible for releasing the string returned by the `-mutableCopy` message.

Answer (score 4):

Sort of:

```
NSMutableString *mutableString = [NSMutableString stringWithString:@"mutableString value"];
```

Answer (score 0):

Case 2 works, but doesn't create a mutable string; it just puts an `NSString` into an `NSMutableString` pointer. The object is still a constant literal string, and sending something like `appendString:` to it will cause a runtime error.

You need to allocate a new `NSMutableString` via either `stringWithString:` or `alloc` followed by `initWithString:`. You could also create an empty string and then use `setString:`, if you prefer.